# How to write a SQL query for joining of tables with several conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

[image]

I need to get this table:

[image]

One date should correspond to one rate. The rate is selected as follows:

1. If the dates in the two tables coincide, the date from Table 1 is assigned the corresponding rate from Table 2. (for example, for dates 31/01/2014, 31/03/2014, 31/01/2015, you can use the usual left join).
2. If there is no corresponding date in Table 2 (February 28, 2014), it is necessary to take the last date of the month (from Table 2 (25-02-2014), where there is a rate). Therefore, the date on 28-02-2014 must be assigned a rate of 18.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Might be worth looking into `APPLY` and `TOP`.

Comment: @ Robert . The problem with the date February 28, 2014.  When I use left join this date assigned as NULL. But I need rate 18 in this date (the last day in february is February 25, 2014). I solved my problem. But script is complex. I would like to make it easy:

Answer (score 0):

```
--first table
SELECT t2.*,
cast(datepart(mm,[date]) as varchar)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,[date]) as varchar) as 
MonthYear
into #tab1
FROM [BP].[dbo].[test1] t2;


----------------------------------------------
--second table
SELECT t.*,
cast(datepart(mm,[date]) as varchar)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,[date]) as varchar) as 
MonthYear,
row_number() over(partition BY 
cast(datepart(mm,[date]) as varchar)+' '+cast(datepart(yyyy,[date]) as varchar) 
ORDER BY [date] desc) num

into #tab2
FROM
[BP].[dbo].[test2] t
order by [date]

------------------------------------------------
-- result table
select t1.*, t2.rate
from #tab1 t1 left join (select rate, MonthYear  from #tab2 where num = 1) t2 on 
t1.MonthYear = t2.MonthYear 
order by [date];

select *
from [BP].[dbo].[test2]
```